# MS Access - VBA - How to escape special characters

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I am inserting rows into Access table from a Excel sheet, one of he column in the excel sheet can have any special characters in it. So how can I insert those data exactly as they were in excel sheet. Since I don't know the list of special chars that can be in the data, so I cannot use Replace function.

Regards,
Tushar

Comment: How are you currently inserting the data into access? If you're using ADO, you can use parameters which will escape special characters.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, I have the following data taken from Wikipedia:

Chinese i/tʃaɪˈniːz/ (汉语 / 漢語; Hànyǔ or 中文; Zhōngwén)
Hindi (हिन्दी), or more precisely Modern Standard Hindi (मानक हिन्दी)
or عربي ,عربى
Russian (ру́сский язы́к, russky yazyk, pronounced [ˈruskʲɪj jɪˈzɨk]) is a Slavic

Using Transferspreadsheet, which can also be used with an Access Application Object from Excel, though that is not illustrated here:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
   "Languages", "C:Docs\Book2.xlsx", , "Sheet1$"
```

I get identical data:

Chinese i/tʃaɪˈniːz/ (汉语 / 漢語; Hànyǔ or 中文; Zhōngwén)
Hindi (हिन्दी), or more precisely Modern Standard Hindi (मानक हिन्दी)
or عربي ,عربى
Russian (ру́сский язы́к, russky yazyk, pronounced [ˈruskʲɪj jɪˈzɨk]) is a Slavic